# accessing a (traditional) record's fields

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers

I have an array of traditional records.

How can I access a field of the Nth record when I know the address of the record's start, field's offset and field's type ?
eg.

```
 type 
 Tstring = string[20];
 TRecord = packed record
  aInteger : integer;
  aDouble  : double;
  aString  : Tstring ;
  bString  : string;
end;

var
aArray : array[0..N] of Trecord;
p : pointer;

.... 
p := pointer(cardinal(aArray[5])+12); // 12 = offset of field "aString"
writeln(Tstring(p^);
```

and so on...

this doesn't work as I expected. Where i'm wrong, please ?

Comment: Please add a language tag and explain a bit about what you mean by traditional record in this context?

Comment: @paisanco looks like some flavor of pascal, perhaps [object pascal](http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/Structured_Types#Records_.28traditional.29)

Comment: Why would you need to do this? If you know `aArray[5]` is a `TRecord`, why not just typecast and access directly with `TRecord(aArray[5]).aString`?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i use Delphi (XE10). I can't use the field's name directly because i store only a single (general) reference of it and i use it later as many times as i have to. Maybe using RTTI is a better way but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: I think that the problem is the way data stored in the heap (up-down). The offsets are negative but i don't know how to read them.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> doesn't work as I expected

I realize what code you've posted was copied in-between attempts to make it work, but next time, **please** post code after you've resolved syntax errors. Also, please include how it *doesn't work*, don't just ask us to debug for you.

## Enough ranting

I've resolved a type error, so code now works but still very *hairy*.

```
p := pointer(cardinal(@aArray[5])+12); // 12 = offset of field "aString"
writeln(Tstring(p^));
```

Basically, you forgot to take address of `aArray` before casting it to arithmetics-enabled `Cardinal` type.

That's why typecasting considered unsafe. A type error was well hidden behind the other typecast.

Comment: You are right! thanks a lot.